# Filtering a Model with a Foreignkey with a list of other models?

Tags: django

I want to filter the org collectors by their foreign key `org_data` by a list of `org_data` with the Github type.

```
OrgCollector.objects.filter(
org_data=OrgData.objects.filter(
            data_type=DataTypeEnum.GITHUB
        ))
```

I currently have this but it does not work. What do I do instead?

Running through the list with a for loop works, but I expect that there is a better way.

I also tried `org_data__in` but that did not seem to work either.

Comment: Share your models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
OrgCollector.objects.filter(
    org_data__data_type=DataTypeEnum.GITHUB
)
```

this will look "*through*" the relation and thus retrieve `OrgCollector`s for which the `data_type` of the `org_data` is `DataTypeEnum.GITHUB`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly and you have added the correct code, this is what you can do:

```
# Get ids of org_data
org_data_ids = OrgData.objects.filter(
            data_type=DataTypeEnum.GITHUB
        ).values_list('id', flat=True)

result = OrgCollector.objects.filter(org_data_id__in=org_data_ids)
```

or

```
# If the above one is creating duplicate results
result = OrgCollector.objects.filter(org_data_id__in=org_data_ids).distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the enum type, it is not matching with the **string** but with the enum type.

Try this query

```
OrgCollector.objects.filter(
org_data=OrgData.objects.filter(
            data_type=DataTypeEnum.GITHUB.value
        ))
```